# Return WP_Error as WP_REST_Response

Tags: rest-api, http-api, wp-error

I have a `http` request to `WP REST API` that can resolve in a success or a failure status

The success gets handled by `WP_REST_Response`, and if any error occurs this is handled by `WP_Error`, both returned if that's the case

However, in both cases when I receive the server response I don't get any of the messages I've added

```php
    public function myFunction($request = null)
    {
        $response = array();
        $parameters = $request->get_json_params();
        $error = new WP_Error();

        if (success) {
                $response['code'] = 200;
                $response['message'] = __("Great", "great");
            } else {
                $error->add(406, __("nope", 'almost'), array('status' => 400));
                return $error;
            }

        return new WP_REST_Response($response, 200);
    }
```

If I inspect the response that I receive, I cannot have access to any message, I only receive

```
Response {
  body: (...)
  bodyUsed: true
  headers: Headers {}
  ok: true
  redirected: false
  status: 200
  statusText: "OK"
  url: "..."
  __proto__: Response
}
```

How does it work?

Answer (score 1):

Already found, if I parse the response `response.json()` I get the messages in both cases